# Warning: Incompatible Pointer Type when checking for open process

Tags: c

I've got a warning saying "Incompatible Pointer Type", and I don't know how to fix it. Im writing in C and compiling in TinyCC.

```
do {
    if (wcscmp(pe32.szExeFile, L"csgo.exe") == 0) {
        *handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pe32.th32ProcessID);
        *pid = pe32.th32ProcessID;
        return (*handle && *pid);
    }
} while (Process32Next(snapshot, &pe32));
```

The warning is on the wcscmp line. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Why do you think the compiler requires a declaration? Is someone who reads the code supposed to guess what `handle` and `pid` types are?

Comment: Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please. At least, please show us the definition of `pe32`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using UNICODE version of struct and function explicitly.

```
PROCESSENTRY32W pe32;

do {
    if (wcscmp(pe32.szExeFile, L"csgo.exe") == 0) {
        *handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pe32.th32ProcessID);
        *pid = pe32.th32ProcessID;
        return (*handle && *pid);
    }
} while (Process32NextW(snapshot, &pe32));
```